# How do I load two fragments vertically in the same layout?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-framelayout

I am making an app for my university's SafeWalk program and I am trying to make an activity that will display a map fragment with a button bar below it with emergency call buttons. The problem I am running in to is that when I load the following layout file, only the map fragment is displayed, and not the buttons along the bottom.

Note: I am also using a navigation drawer in this layout so I have included that code in case it is conflicting.

I have tried changing the layout_width and layout_height values of the two parent FrameLayouts 
and I only can obtain one of two results, a full page of map, or a full page of my buttons (stretched to the top). I can attach the layout for the CallButtonFragment if necessary, but it is a horizontal linear layout with the button bar style containing two buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/content_frame" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:name="edu.purdue.SafeWalk.CallButtonFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Following the suggestion of Android-er-naut below, I have this result: 
(It is an improvement, but the buttons need to be a bit larger and fit the width of the screen.)

[image: Using the suggestion from the below answer, I get this.]

Comment: Besides taking the `RelativeLayout` take `LinearLayout` and set its orientation to vertical

Comment: No change, the map takes up the entire screen.

Comment: @vidia even if you change `match_parent` height to something else so that each of the fragments isn't as high as the full screen?

Comment: But dont the layout attributes in the fragments apply to the FrameLayout parents and not the full screen?

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:name="edu.purdue.SafeWalk.CallButtonFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well I tried it on an AVD (I don't have my cable on me for my real phone) and got a crash because the AVD doesn't have play services... oops. I will test it when I get home, but I believe I tried a linear layout already and it didn't work. Doesn't hurt to try again though.

Comment: I updated my answer with the result of your suggestion. The buttons are now showing, but they need to be larger...